# How to loop through "users" and return the value of each "name"

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to loop through "users" and return the value of each "name".

From what I can tell the loop works, but when returning the value of "name" it comes up as "undefined" four times.

JS:

```
for(var i = 0; i < customer.users.length; i++){
            console.log(customer.users.name)
        }
```

JSON:

```
{
  "users":[
    {
      "user_id": "123",
      "name": "test",
      "xp_amount": 25
    },
    {
      "user_id": "456 ",
      "name": "test1",
      "xp_amount": 25
    },
    {
      "user_id": "789",
      "name": "test2",
      "xp_amount": 25
    },
    {
      "user_id": "101",
      "name": "test3",
      "xp_amount": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `console.log(customer.users[i].name)` -> `customer.users` is an array, you need to access each value by index, that's why you use `[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the `name` property of the current user object inside loop based on index `i` value like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < customer.users.length; i++) {
   console.log(customer.users[i].name)
}
```

Also, using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) you can do it like:

```
customer.users.forEach(function (user) {
  console.log(user.name);
});
```

In this case, the index is not needed as the `user` variable is already the needed object here.

Using ES6 this can be done even less code like:

```
customer.users.forEach(({name}) => console.log(name));
```